# Как наиболее оптимально заполнить таблицу данными из массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

Всем привет. Уже несколько дней не могу найти решение вопроса. У меня есть массив объектов, как с помощью цикла или с помощью метода наиболее оптимально заполнить этими данными таблицу в Реакт? Вот сам массив:

```html
  [
  {
    "date": "2022-09-24",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "reportedCurrency": "USD",
    "cik": "0000320193",
    "fillingDate": "2022-10-28",
    "acceptedDate": "2022-10-27 18:01:14",
    "calendarYear": "2022",
    "period": "FY",
    "cashAndCashEquivalents": 23646000000,
    "shortTermInvestments": 24658000000,
    "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 48304000000,
    "netReceivables": 60932000000,
    "inventory": 4946000000,
    "otherCurrentAssets": 21223000000,
    "totalCurrentAssets": 135405000000,
    "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 42117000000,
    "goodwill": 0,
    "intangibleAssets": 0,
    "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
    "longTermInvestments": 120805000000,
    "taxAssets": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentAssets": 54428000000,
    "totalNonCurrentAssets": 217350000000,
    "otherAssets": 0,
    "totalAssets": 352755000000,
    "accountPayables": 64115000000,
    "shortTermDebt": 21110000000,
    "taxPayables": 0,
    "deferredRevenue": 7912000000,
    "otherCurrentLiabilities": 60845000000,
    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 153982000000,
    "longTermDebt": 98959000000,
    "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
    "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 49142000000,
    "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 148101000000,
    "otherLiabilities": 0,
    "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
    "totalLiabilities": 302083000000,
    "preferredStock": 0,
    "commonStock": 64849000000,
    "retainedEarnings": -3068000000,
    "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -11109000000,
    "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
    "totalStockholdersEquity": 50672000000,
    "totalEquity": 50672000000,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 352755000000,
    "minorityInterest": 0,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 352755000000,
    "totalInvestments": 145463000000,
    "totalDebt": 120069000000,
    "netDebt": 96423000000,
    "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/0000320193-22-000108-index.htm",
    "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm"
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-09-25",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "reportedCurrency": "USD",
    "cik": "0000320193",
    "fillingDate": "2021-10-29",
    "acceptedDate": "2021-10-28 18:04:28",
    "calendarYear": "2021",
    "period": "FY",
    "cashAndCashEquivalents": 34940000000,
    "shortTermInvestments": 27699000000,
    "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 62639000000,
    "netReceivables": 51506000000,
    "inventory": 6580000000,
    "otherCurrentAssets": 14111000000,
    "totalCurrentAssets": 134836000000,
    "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 39440000000,
    "goodwill": 0,
    "intangibleAssets": 0,
    "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
    "longTermInvestments": 127877000000,
    "taxAssets": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentAssets": 48849000000,
    "totalNonCurrentAssets": 216166000000,
    "otherAssets": 0,
    "totalAssets": 351002000000,
    "accountPayables": 54763000000,
    "shortTermDebt": 15613000000,
    "taxPayables": 0,
    "deferredRevenue": 7612000000,
    "otherCurrentLiabilities": 47493000000,
    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 125481000000,
    "longTermDebt": 109106000000,
    "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
    "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 53325000000,
    "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 162431000000,
    "otherLiabilities": 0,
    "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
    "totalLiabilities": 287912000000,
    "preferredStock": 0,
    "commonStock": 57365000000,
    "retainedEarnings": 5562000000,
    "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": 163000000,
    "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
    "totalStockholdersEquity": 63090000000,
    "totalEquity": 63090000000,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 351002000000,
    "minorityInterest": 0,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 351002000000,
    "totalInvestments": 155576000000,
    "totalDebt": 124719000000,
    "netDebt": 89779000000,
    "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019321000105/0000320193-21-000105-index.htm",
    "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019321000105/aapl-20210925.htm"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-09-26",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "reportedCurrency": "USD",
    "cik": "0000320193",
    "fillingDate": "2020-10-30",
    "acceptedDate": "2020-10-29 18:06:25",
    "calendarYear": "2020",
    "period": "FY",
    "cashAndCashEquivalents": 38016000000,
    "shortTermInvestments": 52927000000,
    "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 90943000000,
    "netReceivables": 37445000000,
    "inventory": 4061000000,
    "otherCurrentAssets": 11264000000,
    "totalCurrentAssets": 143713000000,
    "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 36766000000,
    "goodwill": 0,
    "intangibleAssets": 0,
    "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
    "longTermInvestments": 100887000000,
    "taxAssets": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentAssets": 42522000000,
    "totalNonCurrentAssets": 180175000000,
    "otherAssets": 0,
    "totalAssets": 323888000000,
    "accountPayables": 42296000000,
    "shortTermDebt": 13769000000,
    "taxPayables": 0,
    "deferredRevenue": 6643000000,
    "otherCurrentLiabilities": 42684000000,
    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 105392000000,
    "longTermDebt": 98667000000,
    "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
    "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 54490000000,
    "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 153157000000,
    "otherLiabilities": 0,
    "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
    "totalLiabilities": 258549000000,
    "preferredStock": 0,
    "commonStock": 50779000000,
    "retainedEarnings": 14966000000,
    "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -406000000,
    "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
    "totalStockholdersEquity": 65339000000,
    "totalEquity": 65339000000,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 323888000000,
    "minorityInterest": 0,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 323888000000,
    "totalInvestments": 153814000000,
    "totalDebt": 112436000000,
    "netDebt": 74420000000,
    "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/0000320193-20-000096-index.htm",
    "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/aapl-20200926.htm"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-09-28",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "reportedCurrency": "USD",
    "cik": "0000320193",
    "fillingDate": "2019-10-31",
    "acceptedDate": "2019-10-30 18:12:36",
    "calendarYear": "2019",
    "period": "FY",
    "cashAndCashEquivalents": 48844000000,
    "shortTermInvestments": 51713000000,
    "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 100557000000,
    "netReceivables": 45804000000,
    "inventory": 4106000000,
    "otherCurrentAssets": 12352000000,
    "totalCurrentAssets": 162819000000,
    "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 37378000000,
    "goodwill": 0,
    "intangibleAssets": 0,
    "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
    "longTermInvestments": 105341000000,
    "taxAssets": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentAssets": 32978000000,
    "totalNonCurrentAssets": 175697000000,
    "otherAssets": 0,
    "totalAssets": 338516000000,
    "accountPayables": 46236000000,
    "shortTermDebt": 16240000000,
    "taxPayables": 0,
    "deferredRevenue": 5522000000,
    "otherCurrentLiabilities": 37720000000,
    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 105718000000,
    "longTermDebt": 91807000000,
    "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
    "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 50503000000,
    "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 142310000000,
    "otherLiabilities": 0,
    "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
    "totalLiabilities": 248028000000,
    "preferredStock": 0,
    "commonStock": 45174000000,
    "retainedEarnings": 45898000000,
    "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -584000000,
    "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
    "totalStockholdersEquity": 90488000000,
    "totalEquity": 90488000000,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 338516000000,
    "minorityInterest": 0,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 338516000000,
    "totalInvestments": 157054000000,
    "totalDebt": 108047000000,
    "netDebt": 59203000000,
    "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/0000320193-19-000119-index.html",
    "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/a10-k20199282019.htm"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-09-29",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "reportedCurrency": "USD",
    "cik": "0000320193",
    "fillingDate": "2018-11-05",
    "acceptedDate": "2018-11-05 08:01:40",
    "calendarYear": "2018",
    "period": "FY",
    "cashAndCashEquivalents": 25913000000,
    "shortTermInvestments": 40388000000,
    "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 66301000000,
    "netReceivables": 48995000000,
    "inventory": 3956000000,
    "otherCurrentAssets": 12087000000,
    "totalCurrentAssets": 131339000000,
    "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 41304000000,
    "goodwill": 0,
    "intangibleAssets": 0,
    "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
    "longTermInvestments": 170799000000,
    "taxAssets": 0,
    "otherNonCurrentAssets": 22283000000,
    "totalNonCurrentAssets": 234386000000,
    "otherAssets": 0,
    "totalAssets": 365725000000,
    "accountPayables": 55888000000,
    "shortTermDebt": 20748000000,
    "taxPayables": 0,
    "deferredRevenue": 7543000000,
    "otherCurrentLiabilities": 32687000000,
    "totalCurrentLiabilities": 116866000000,
    "longTermDebt": 93735000000,
    "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 2797000000,
    "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 426000000,
    "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 44754000000,
    "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 141712000000,
    "otherLiabilities": 0,
    "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
    "totalLiabilities": 258578000000,
    "preferredStock": 0,
    "commonStock": 40201000000,
    "retainedEarnings": 70400000000,
    "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -3454000000,
    "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
    "totalStockholdersEquity": 107147000000,
    "totalEquity": 107147000000,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 365725000000,
    "minorityInterest": 0,
    "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 365725000000,
    "totalInvestments": 211187000000,
    "totalDebt": 114483000000,
    "netDebt": 88570000000,
    "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/0000320193-18-000145-index.html",
    "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/a10-k20189292018.htm"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

> как с помощью цикла или с помощью метода наиболее оптимально заполнить этими данными таблицу в Реакт?

Как некую иллюстрацию для заполнения таблицы - можно предложить вот такой пример...

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.querySelector('#root'))

function Table() {
  const [tbl, setTbl] = React.useState(data())
  return (
    <table border='1'>
      <tbody>
        {tbl.map((o, i) => <Row key={i} row={o}/>)}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
function Row({row}) {
  const col = ['date', 'symbol', 'reportedCurrency']
  return (
    <tr>
      {col.map(key => <Col key={key} name={key} row={row}/>)}
    </tr>
  )
}
function Col({name, row}) {
  return (
    <td>
      {row[name]}
    </td>
  )
}

function data() {
  return [{
      "date": "2022-09-24",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "reportedCurrency": "USD",
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "fillingDate": "2022-10-28",
      "acceptedDate": "2022-10-27 18:01:14",
      "calendarYear": "2022",
      "period": "FY",
      "cashAndCashEquivalents": 23646000000,
      "shortTermInvestments": 24658000000,
      "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 48304000000,
      "netReceivables": 60932000000,
      "inventory": 4946000000,
      "otherCurrentAssets": 21223000000,
      "totalCurrentAssets": 135405000000,
      "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 42117000000,
      "goodwill": 0,
      "intangibleAssets": 0,
      "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
      "longTermInvestments": 120805000000,
      "taxAssets": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentAssets": 54428000000,
      "totalNonCurrentAssets": 217350000000,
      "otherAssets": 0,
      "totalAssets": 352755000000,
      "accountPayables": 64115000000,
      "shortTermDebt": 21110000000,
      "taxPayables": 0,
      "deferredRevenue": 7912000000,
      "otherCurrentLiabilities": 60845000000,
      "totalCurrentLiabilities": 153982000000,
      "longTermDebt": 98959000000,
      "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
      "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 49142000000,
      "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 148101000000,
      "otherLiabilities": 0,
      "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
      "totalLiabilities": 302083000000,
      "preferredStock": 0,
      "commonStock": 64849000000,
      "retainedEarnings": -3068000000,
      "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -11109000000,
      "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
      "totalStockholdersEquity": 50672000000,
      "totalEquity": 50672000000,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 352755000000,
      "minorityInterest": 0,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 352755000000,
      "totalInvestments": 145463000000,
      "totalDebt": 120069000000,
      "netDebt": 96423000000,
      "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/0000320193-22-000108-index.htm",
      "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019322000108/aapl-20220924.htm"
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-09-25",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "reportedCurrency": "USD",
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "fillingDate": "2021-10-29",
      "acceptedDate": "2021-10-28 18:04:28",
      "calendarYear": "2021",
      "period": "FY",
      "cashAndCashEquivalents": 34940000000,
      "shortTermInvestments": 27699000000,
      "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 62639000000,
      "netReceivables": 51506000000,
      "inventory": 6580000000,
      "otherCurrentAssets": 14111000000,
      "totalCurrentAssets": 134836000000,
      "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 39440000000,
      "goodwill": 0,
      "intangibleAssets": 0,
      "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
      "longTermInvestments": 127877000000,
      "taxAssets": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentAssets": 48849000000,
      "totalNonCurrentAssets": 216166000000,
      "otherAssets": 0,
      "totalAssets": 351002000000,
      "accountPayables": 54763000000,
      "shortTermDebt": 15613000000,
      "taxPayables": 0,
      "deferredRevenue": 7612000000,
      "otherCurrentLiabilities": 47493000000,
      "totalCurrentLiabilities": 125481000000,
      "longTermDebt": 109106000000,
      "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
      "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 53325000000,
      "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 162431000000,
      "otherLiabilities": 0,
      "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
      "totalLiabilities": 287912000000,
      "preferredStock": 0,
      "commonStock": 57365000000,
      "retainedEarnings": 5562000000,
      "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": 163000000,
      "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
      "totalStockholdersEquity": 63090000000,
      "totalEquity": 63090000000,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 351002000000,
      "minorityInterest": 0,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 351002000000,
      "totalInvestments": 155576000000,
      "totalDebt": 124719000000,
      "netDebt": 89779000000,
      "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019321000105/0000320193-21-000105-index.htm",
      "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019321000105/aapl-20210925.htm"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-09-26",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "reportedCurrency": "USD",
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "fillingDate": "2020-10-30",
      "acceptedDate": "2020-10-29 18:06:25",
      "calendarYear": "2020",
      "period": "FY",
      "cashAndCashEquivalents": 38016000000,
      "shortTermInvestments": 52927000000,
      "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 90943000000,
      "netReceivables": 37445000000,
      "inventory": 4061000000,
      "otherCurrentAssets": 11264000000,
      "totalCurrentAssets": 143713000000,
      "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 36766000000,
      "goodwill": 0,
      "intangibleAssets": 0,
      "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
      "longTermInvestments": 100887000000,
      "taxAssets": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentAssets": 42522000000,
      "totalNonCurrentAssets": 180175000000,
      "otherAssets": 0,
      "totalAssets": 323888000000,
      "accountPayables": 42296000000,
      "shortTermDebt": 13769000000,
      "taxPayables": 0,
      "deferredRevenue": 6643000000,
      "otherCurrentLiabilities": 42684000000,
      "totalCurrentLiabilities": 105392000000,
      "longTermDebt": 98667000000,
      "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
      "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 54490000000,
      "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 153157000000,
      "otherLiabilities": 0,
      "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
      "totalLiabilities": 258549000000,
      "preferredStock": 0,
      "commonStock": 50779000000,
      "retainedEarnings": 14966000000,
      "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -406000000,
      "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
      "totalStockholdersEquity": 65339000000,
      "totalEquity": 65339000000,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 323888000000,
      "minorityInterest": 0,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 323888000000,
      "totalInvestments": 153814000000,
      "totalDebt": 112436000000,
      "netDebt": 74420000000,
      "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/0000320193-20-000096-index.htm",
      "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/aapl-20200926.htm"
    },
    {
      "date": "2019-09-28",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "reportedCurrency": "USD",
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "fillingDate": "2019-10-31",
      "acceptedDate": "2019-10-30 18:12:36",
      "calendarYear": "2019",
      "period": "FY",
      "cashAndCashEquivalents": 48844000000,
      "shortTermInvestments": 51713000000,
      "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 100557000000,
      "netReceivables": 45804000000,
      "inventory": 4106000000,
      "otherCurrentAssets": 12352000000,
      "totalCurrentAssets": 162819000000,
      "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 37378000000,
      "goodwill": 0,
      "intangibleAssets": 0,
      "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
      "longTermInvestments": 105341000000,
      "taxAssets": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentAssets": 32978000000,
      "totalNonCurrentAssets": 175697000000,
      "otherAssets": 0,
      "totalAssets": 338516000000,
      "accountPayables": 46236000000,
      "shortTermDebt": 16240000000,
      "taxPayables": 0,
      "deferredRevenue": 5522000000,
      "otherCurrentLiabilities": 37720000000,
      "totalCurrentLiabilities": 105718000000,
      "longTermDebt": 91807000000,
      "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 0,
      "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 50503000000,
      "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 142310000000,
      "otherLiabilities": 0,
      "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
      "totalLiabilities": 248028000000,
      "preferredStock": 0,
      "commonStock": 45174000000,
      "retainedEarnings": 45898000000,
      "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -584000000,
      "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
      "totalStockholdersEquity": 90488000000,
      "totalEquity": 90488000000,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 338516000000,
      "minorityInterest": 0,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 338516000000,
      "totalInvestments": 157054000000,
      "totalDebt": 108047000000,
      "netDebt": 59203000000,
      "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/0000320193-19-000119-index.html",
      "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/a10-k20199282019.htm"
    },
    {
      "date": "2018-09-29",
      "symbol": "AAPL",
      "reportedCurrency": "USD",
      "cik": "0000320193",
      "fillingDate": "2018-11-05",
      "acceptedDate": "2018-11-05 08:01:40",
      "calendarYear": "2018",
      "period": "FY",
      "cashAndCashEquivalents": 25913000000,
      "shortTermInvestments": 40388000000,
      "cashAndShortTermInvestments": 66301000000,
      "netReceivables": 48995000000,
      "inventory": 3956000000,
      "otherCurrentAssets": 12087000000,
      "totalCurrentAssets": 131339000000,
      "propertyPlantEquipmentNet": 41304000000,
      "goodwill": 0,
      "intangibleAssets": 0,
      "goodwillAndIntangibleAssets": 0,
      "longTermInvestments": 170799000000,
      "taxAssets": 0,
      "otherNonCurrentAssets": 22283000000,
      "totalNonCurrentAssets": 234386000000,
      "otherAssets": 0,
      "totalAssets": 365725000000,
      "accountPayables": 55888000000,
      "shortTermDebt": 20748000000,
      "taxPayables": 0,
      "deferredRevenue": 7543000000,
      "otherCurrentLiabilities": 32687000000,
      "totalCurrentLiabilities": 116866000000,
      "longTermDebt": 93735000000,
      "deferredRevenueNonCurrent": 2797000000,
      "deferredTaxLiabilitiesNonCurrent": 426000000,
      "otherNonCurrentLiabilities": 44754000000,
      "totalNonCurrentLiabilities": 141712000000,
      "otherLiabilities": 0,
      "capitalLeaseObligations": 0,
      "totalLiabilities": 258578000000,
      "preferredStock": 0,
      "commonStock": 40201000000,
      "retainedEarnings": 70400000000,
      "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeLoss": -3454000000,
      "othertotalStockholdersEquity": 0,
      "totalStockholdersEquity": 107147000000,
      "totalEquity": 107147000000,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndStockholdersEquity": 365725000000,
      "minorityInterest": 0,
      "totalLiabilitiesAndTotalEquity": 365725000000,
      "totalInvestments": 211187000000,
      "totalDebt": 114483000000,
      "netDebt": 88570000000,
      "link": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/0000320193-18-000145-index.html",
      "finalLink": "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/a10-k20189292018.htm"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Это решение сьедает всю память у браузера

Comment: @ДмитрийКудрявцев, так это обычное дело. Где-то ведь нужно хранить все твое богатство...

Comment: Мои года - мое богатство)

Comment: @ДмитрийКудрявцев, если у тебя данные для таблицы такие огромные - читай их порциями. Делай т.н. "постраничный" просмотр. Т.о. будешь использовать только некую часть памяти в браузере.